# Getting data from two tables with a junction table

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

So i have a user table which has userId and schoolId which points to a userInstitution table consisting of userId and courseId. Pointing to the userInstitution table is the course table as well which consists of courseId and schoolId.

user table --> userInstitution table <-- course table

I want to update a user to have a certain course assigned to them and i also want to know how i can select a user with a certain course.

Comment: And what is a `program`?, a course?, various courses?

Comment: What program, exactly? Are you using program and course interchangeably?

Comment: @GordonLinoff the middle table userCourse has a userId which is in the users table and it has a courseId which is in the course table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To assign a course to a user.

```
insert into userInstitution 
(userid, courseid)
values
(the ids for the course and user)
```

To select users for a certain course

```
select u.name
from users u join userInstitution ui on u.userid = ui.userid
join course c on ui.courseid = c.courseid
where c.name = 'name of course'
```

Answer (score 0):

Select user.* from user 
Join userInstitution 
On user.id = userInstitution.userId
Join course
On course.id = userInstitution.courseId
Where course.id=321

This sql will give you all users which are enrolled to course with id 321